Proc macro for terse field setting
I want to write a Macro that turns:
Text!(
  data: "foo",
)

into:
TextBuilder::default()
  .data("foo")
  .build()

It seems like I need to write a proc_macro for this.
Now I can match for both TokenTree::Ident and TokenTree::Punct to setup the output tokens .data. For ("foo") , AFAIU, I would need to create a TokenTree::Group.
Not sure how to collect all Tokens to add them to Group then.
Or whether this is the correct approach for this...

I don't think you need a proc_macro here, a simple macro_rules!() should do the trick:
macro_rules! Text {
    ($($k:ident: $v:expr),*$(,)?) => {
        TextBuilder::default()
            $(.$k($v))*
            .build()
    }
}

Here's a playground; hit Tools > Expand macros to see the result.
